# Mediarecorder infolister getting 895

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder to record user sound in my application and all the time I am testing with real device and it is working properly. But in some devices it shows a warning. The MediaRecorder's OnInfoListener what argument is giving me 895.The code i am using is

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(getAudioRecordFileName());
recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
```

and the OnInfoListener is

```
private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Warning: " + what + ", " + extra,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

What is the problem here, what type of error is this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out on my device info code 895 meant recording is in progress.
That means you don't need to stop the recording.